# Best way to do a php action when a link is clicked?

Tags: php, html

I've got a database including uploaded documents. The link to an uploaded document is:

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];     
htmlout('/database/docs/'.$cand['id'].'/'.$docs['filename']);?>">
    <img src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>/database/img/cv.png" border="0">
</a>
```

I want to call a function which writes to an activity log when a link like that is clicked, e.g. `writelog($userid, $msg)` so I can see what user has viewed what document.

What would be the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a js/jquery click event on the image and have that make an ajax call to your php writelog function. Whether this is the best method is up for debate but that is how I would accomplish the task.

```
<a class="clicked_link">

$(".clicked_link").click(function() {
  var file_name = .....
  $.ajax({
    ...
  })
});
```

Here is a non-js version:
Have the link load a php page that loads the image and then every time that page is called have it display the image and call the writelog function

```
<a href="load_image.php?filename=PHPCODE">

<php
$file = $_GET['filename'];
writelog(one, two);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to avoid javascript as that can be edited client side

Comment: Updated w/ a non js solution

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax function to send request to PHP Script when user click on anchor i.e.

> > Note: This code requires jQuery

```
$(function(){ 
    $('a').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $.post('<URL_TO_PHP_FILE>', { data: { userid: 1, message: 'clicked' }, function(){
                               alert('Log has been written');
           } });

    });
});
```

In PHP, you can write your code to save log.